# Confidence Interval problem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Which of the following will result in a wider confidence interval? Check all that apply.

```
Larger sample size
Higher level of confidence
Larger population standard deviation
Larger population mean
Larger sample mean
```

So after running some numbers, I believe 2,3, and 4 are correct because they appeared to work however apparently that's incorrect. Could anyone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\Pr\biggl\{\overline X - \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2) \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \le \mu \le \overline X + \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2) \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\biggr\}=1-\alpha.
$$

Comment: How does this help me understand my questoin?

Comment: @Jacob This is how confidence intervals are constructed. $n$ is the sample size, $1-\alpha$ is the level of confidence, $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation, $\mu$ is the population mean, $\bar X$ is the sample mean. These are all standard notations. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Examples) for more details.

Comment: So the correct answer would be just 2 and 5?

Comment: @Jacob The sample mean does not affect the width of the interval. The correct answers are 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.